# SQL data that does not match Regex isnt filtered out

Tags: python, sql, regex, passwords

I have been playing around trying to set up a regular expression argument that looks at password strings in an SQL file and moves the IDs of the records into a list. When made True all entries are added to the list, yet the one incorrect password is still added to the list even though it should not pass the regex argument.

```
def passwordCheck(filename):
  idList = []
  con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
  cur = con.cursor()
  for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data;"):
    row[5] = str(row[5])
    regScan = re.match(r"(r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$')", row[5])
    for match in row[5]:
      idList.append(row[0])
  return idList

def validPass(filename):
  idList = []
  con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
  cur = con.cursor()
  for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data;"):
    string = pd.Series(row[5])
    string[string.str.match(r"(r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$')")==True]
    if True:
      idList.append(row[0])
  return idList
```

Here I have two methods one using regular expressions alone with the SQL file, and the other trying to use pandas to reach the same end.

One password in my database is just "password", while the others have 1 lowercase, uppercase number and special character. My aim is so the incorrect password is flagged and its corresponding user id is placed in the list. So my output should be something like:

```
[7]
```

Yet it always comes either blank when I set the argument to False, or all entries are added when I set to True, despite ID: 7 being the only incorrect entry that should be flagged.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This line: `if True:` means that your code will *always* execute what's in this `if` statement. You want to instead check that the result of your regex is True.

Comment: I see what you mean, so what should I have instead to check if the result is True or False?

Comment: Try this: `if not string.str.match('^(?=.*[0-9]$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])'):`. I adjusted the regex because yours wasn't working in the way I expected it to, but feel free to continue to use yours if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1 . `regScan = re.match(r"(r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$')", row[5])`

and

2. `string[string.str.match(r"(r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$')")==True]`

are both wrong.

Do not place a raw string literal inside a raw string literal. Instead of 1) use

```py
regScan = re.match(r'(?=.*[0-9]).*\W', row[5])
```

Instead of 2) use

```py
if not string.str.match(r'(?=.*[0-9]).*\W'):
    idList.append(row[0])
```

You need no `^` anchor, `match` searches for a match at the beginning of the string.

Quick regex reference:

1. `(?=.*[0-9])` requires a digit in the string
2. `\W` searches for a character that is neither letter, digit nor an underscore (did you mean to use `\w`?)

Comment: I have tried both edits and both came with an "unbalanced parenthesis" error. I have fixed that with both as it was an issue with your bracketing, yet now I don't get any7 results. If you would like I could explain further what I am trying to do so it is clear for you, as I only seem to be hitting dead ends.

Comment: @TML Sorry, fixed the issues. But I can only help more if you provide strings that must pass and the strings that must fail the check.